# Opera browser on Ubuntu

Tags: opera

I have installed the Opera browser on Ubuntu 22.04 (on a VPS). When starting in the command line, I get the error message:

`[8410:8410:0505/155636.151776:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY [8410:8410:0505/155636.152212:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize. Exiting.`

echo $display returns only blank spaces.

I would need help, to get the Opera browser to work. I need a browser for pgadmin.

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` is the one to use,  not `echo $display`. Unix/Linux is case sensitive